# React-Native: Can we use JavaScript's 'debounce' function directly or _lodash's debounce is the only option?

Tags: javascript, react-native, debouncing

When i try to use `JavaScript's 'debounce'` as shown below,

```
debounce(() => {
    this.getDataFn(true);
}, 3000);
```

getting an error like `debounce is not defined`. This error is apparent that `react-native` is considering the `debounce` keyword as a normal variable.

Can anybody confirm that,  is `_loadash's debounce` only option or any alternative without going for package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debounce` function is not available out of the box. If you donot want to add a separate package, you can implement your own debounce function as below

```
const debounce = (fn, time) => {
  let timeout;

  return function() {
    const functionCall = () => fn.apply(this, arguments);

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(functionCall, time);
  }
}
```

For full reference please check [Medium](https://medium.com/@TCAS3/debounce-deep-dive-javascript-es6-e6f8d983b7a1)